# Find unexecuted lines of c++ code

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, g++, code-coverage

As part of my unit testing I want to ensure code coverage of the tests. The aim is to place something like `REQUIRE_TEST` macros somewhere in the code and check whether all of these were called.

```
void foo(bool b) {
  if (b) {
    REQUIRE_TEST
    ...
  } else {
    REQUIRE_TEST
    ...
  }
}

void main() {
  foo(true);

  output_all_missed_REQUIRE_macros();
}
```

Ideally the output would include source-file and line of the macro.

My initial idea was to have the macros create static objects that would register themselves in some map and later check whether all of these were called

```
#define REQUIRE_TEST \
        do { \
            static ___RequiredTest requiredTest(__func__, __FILE__, __LINE__);\
            (void)requiredTest;\
            ___RequiredTest::increaseCounter(__func__, __FILE__, __LINE__);\
        } while(false)
```

but the static object are only created when the code is called the first time. So the map only contains functions that are also counted in the next line - missing REQUIRE_TEST macros are not found. the `__attribute__((used))` is ignored in this case.

The gcc has a nice attribute `__attribute__((constructor))`, but apparently chooses to ignore it when placed here (following code instead of the static object)

```
struct teststruct { \
  __attribute__((constructor)) static void bla() {\
    ___RequiredTest::register(__func__, __FILE__, __LINE__); \
  } \
};\
```

as well as for

```
[]() __attribute__((constructor)) { \
  ___RequiredTest::register(__func__, __FILE__, __LINE__); \
};\
```

The only way out I can think of now is a) manually (or via script) analyse the code outside of the regular compilation (uargh) or b) use the `__COUNTER__` macro to count the macros - but then I would not know which specific REQUIRE_TEST macros were not called... (and everything breaks if somebody else decides to use the `__COUNTER__` macro as well...)

> Are there any decent solutions to this problem? What am I missing? It
>   would be nice to have a macro that appends the current line and file
>   so some preprocessor variable whenever it is called - but that is not
>   possible, right?  Are there any other ways to register something to be
>   executed before `main()` that can be done within a function body?

Comment: Research the warnings and command line options for your compiler.  Many compilers have the capability of identifying "dead code".

Comment: TL;DR; Why aren't you use some coverage profiling code injection like [`gcov`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov.html) and analyze the results e.g. using [`lcov`](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov.php)? That might not necessarily really approve for _dead code_, if it's not executed from your test scenarios. A static code analysis tool might serve better to find such dead stuff.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `gcov` is very detailed - but also in code parts where I don't really care. Placing markers like `REQUIRE_TEST` would allow me to specify which parts I care about. It would also be another dependency for everybody I ship my library to - and it feels like c++ is _almost_ able to do what I want... If any of my attempts worked I would have everything I ever wanted. Maybe something like `gcov` will be the only solution in the end - but I would like to know that what I am trying is not possible before "giving up" and adding another dependency...

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
#include <iostream>

static size_t cover() { return 1; }

#define COV() do { static size_t cov[2] __attribute__((section("cov"))) = { __LINE__, cover() }; } while(0)

static void dump_cov()
{
        extern size_t __start_cov, __stop_cov;

        for (size_t* p = &__start_cov; p < &__stop_cov; p += 2)
        {
                std::cout << p[0] << ": " << p[1] << "\n";
        }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        COV();

        if (argc > 1)
                COV();

        if (argc > 2)
                COV();

        dump_cov();
        return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
$ ./cov_test
19: 1
22: 0
25: 0
```

and:

```
$ ./cov_test x
19: 1
22: 1
25: 0
```

and:

```
$ ./cov_test x y
19: 1
22: 1
25: 1
```

Basically, we set up a coverage array in a named memory section (obviously we've used GCC-specific mechanisms for this), which we dump after execution.

We rely on constant initialisation of local statics being performed at startup - which gets the line numbers into the coverage array with coverage flag set to zero - and on initialisation via the function call to `cover()` being performed at first execution of the statement, which sets the coverage flags to 1 for executed lines.  I'm not 100% sure all this is guaranteed by the standard, nor by which versions of the standard (I compiled with `--std=c++11`).

Finally, building with '-O3' also produces correct results (albeit allocated in a different order):

```
$ ./a
25: 0
22: 0
19: 1
```

and:

```
$ ./a x
25: 0
22: 1
19: 1
```

and

```
$ ./a x y
25: 1
22: 1
19: 1
```

Comment: According to the standard, the compiler is allowed to initialize local statics before main - if it wishes to do so. But Initializing it with 0 and adding another code line which increases this number in the macro should work just fine. Thanks for the idea to iterate over this custom section. I will also add the current file name, but it should then pretty much be what I wanted =)

Comment: do you have any idea why this gives a section type conflict when the `COV` macro is used in an inline function?

Answer (score 1):

An ugly but simple approach is for `REQUIRE_TEST` to use `__LINE__` or `__COUNTER__` to construct the name of a unique file-scope static object which it refers to, and which will cause a compiler error if it hasn't been declared.  You then need to manually declare all such objects up front, one for each `REQUIRE_TEST` - but at least you get a compile error if you haven't done so.

Hey, I said it was ugly!

Answer (score 1):

Jeremy gave me the right idea to have a closer look at the sections. His answer works - but only without `inline` functions. With some more research I was able to find the following solution which is just as much gcc dependent (due to the name of the section) but more flexible (and works in inline functions). The macro is now as follows:

```
#define REQUIRE_TEST \
    do { \
        struct ___a{ static void rt() {\
            ___RequiredTest::register_test(__FILE__, __LINE__);\
        } };\
        static auto ___rtp __attribute__((section(".init_array"))) = &___a::rt; \
        (void) ___rtp; \
        ___RequiredTest::increase_counter(__FILE__, __LINE__); \
    } while(false)
```

Placing the function pointer in the section `.init_array` actually places it in the list of initialization functions that are being called before main. This way it can be assured, that the locally defined function is being called before main.