# Inline static data causes a section type conflict

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, elf

I want to put some user defined data into a custom section to be read by the application and an offline analyser at the same time. Assuming the following sample:

```
const int* get_data()
{
  __attribute__((section(".custom")))
  static const int data = 123;

  return & data;
}

inline const int* inline_get_data()
{
  __attribute__((section(".custom")))
  static const int inline_data = 123;

  return & inline_data;
}

int main()
{
  (void) get_data();
  (void) inline_get_data();
  return 0;
}
```

The value of `data` and `inline_data` will appear in the section `.custom`. Clang compiles this example and produces the correct result, just as MSVC does, when the `__attributes__` are replaced by [corresponding pragmas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50bewfwa.aspx).

Unfortunately, GCC 5.2 gives the following error:

```
error: inline_data causes a section type conflict with data
```

The problem boils down to the fact that the two variables have different linkage (`data` is in a section [flagged](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Section.html) with `a`, the section of `inline_data` is flagged with `aG`). GCC 4.9 fails the same way if the second function is not marked as inline but is a template (GCC 5.2 compiles that).

GCC 5.2 also compiles fine if one section name is temporarily changed and manually fixed in the generated assembly.

Is there any known workaround for this issue? I have no control over the function signature,the `*data` variables are produced by a macro provided by me, and they can appear anywhere.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve under the hood here? Seems the workaround is likely to be tightly coupled to the reason for doing this.

Comment: Are the conflicting definitions really in the same source file?
Can you amend the example to show how the files containing the
conflicting definitions are actually related in the program?

Comment: @Mike Kinghan: the example is self containing, this exact single source file reproduces the problem.

Comment: Also see [Compile error "X causes a section type conflict with Y" should provide more information](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82209) in the GCC Issue Tracker.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For the general good, I'll reiterate what you already know and what @Rumbaruk
has already cited: gcc's documentation explicitly restricts the application of the `section` attribute to *global* variables. So
the desired workaround for gcc's behaviour is a way to get gcc not to barf or emit broken code on an unsupported application of a gcc-specific language
extension. We've no right to expect success or to expect a success to be consistently repeatable.

Here comes a long explanation of how and why gcc produces the section-type conflict
compilation error and clang doesn't. Scroll to **Fixes** if impatient, but don't
expect a silver bullet.

For demonstration purposes I'll work with a slightly more lifelike program than
you've posted, viz:

**source.cpp**

```
const int* get_data()
{
    __attribute__((section(".custom")))
    static const int data = 123;

    return & data;
}

inline const int* inline_get_data()
{
    __attribute__((section(".custom")))
    static const int inline_data = 123;

    return & inline_data;
}

const int* other_get_data()
{
    return inline_get_data();
}
```

**header.h**

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
extern const int* get_data();
extern const int* other_get_data();
#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "header.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << (*get_data() + *other_get_data()) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

As it stands, this program reproduces the section-type conflict error when
compiled with gcc 5.2:

```
$ g++-5 -Wall -pedantic -c source.cpp
source.cpp:12:22: error: inline_data causes a section type conflict with data
     static const int inline_data = 123;
                      ^
```

Clang (3.6/3.7) has no complaints:

```
$ clang++ -Wall -pedantic -I. -o prog main.cpp source.cpp 
$ ./prog
246
```

The root of gcc's obstructiveness is the fact that `inline_get_data()` is
an *inline* function with *external linkage* that attributes a linkage section
to its static data in the same translation unit as a *non-inline* function,
`get_data()`, that attributes the same linkage section to its own static data.

The compiler adopts different rules to generate the linkage for `get_data()`
and `inline_get_data()` respectively. `get_data()` is the simple case, `inline_get_data()`
is tricky case.

To see the difference, let's temporarily disarm the gcc section conflict by replacing `"custom"` with `"custom.a"` in `get_data()` and replacing `"custom"` with `"custom.b"` in `inline_get_data()`.

Now we can compile `source.cpp` with gcc and inspect the relevant symbol table entries:

```
$ objdump -C -t source.o | grep get_data
0000000000000000 l     O .custom.a  0000000000000004 get_data()::data
0000000000000000 l    d  .text._Z15inline_get_datav 0000000000000000 .text._Z15inline_get_datav
0000000000000000 g     F .text  000000000000000b get_data()
0000000000000000 u     O .custom.b  0000000000000004 inline_get_data()::inline_data
0000000000000000  w    F .text._Z15inline_get_datav 000000000000000b inline_get_data()
000000000000000b g     F .text  000000000000000b other_get_data()
```

`get_data()`, of course, has been made a global symbol (`g`) and `get_data()::data` made
a local symbol (`l`). But `inline_get_data()` has been made a [weak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol), neither global nor local
symbol (`w`) and `inline_get_data()::inline_data`, although it is syntactically block-scope static,
has been made a *unique global symbol* (`u`). This is a GNU extension of the standard ELF
symbol bindings requiring the runtime linker to ensure that the symbol is unique in the entire
runtime linkage.

In these different linkage stipulations for `inline_get_data()`, gcc is coping as it deems fit
with the fact that the function is *inline with external linkage*. The fact that the function
is *inline* means it must be defined in each translation unit in 
which it is used, and the fact that it has *external linkage* means that all those definitions
must address the same `inline_data()::get_data`. Thus the block-scope static variable must,
for linkage purposes, become a public symbol.

From the same motivation, gcc deals differently with the attributed section `custom.a` in
the setting of `get_data()` and the attributed section `custom.b` in `inline_get_data()`.
Having designated `inline_get_data()::inline_data` a unique global symbol, it wants to
ensure that multiple definitions of this symbol are not introduced by the linkage of
multiple copies the section `custom.b` from different translation units. To that end, it
applies the `GROUP` linker attribute to `custom.b`: this (skipping details) enables it
to generate a `.section` directive that assigns `custom.b` to a named *section-group* and
directs the linker to retain only one copy of that section group. Observe:

```
$ readelf -t source.o
...
...
[ 7] .custom.a
   PROGBITS               PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0000000000000068  0
   0000000000000004 0000000000000000  0                 4
   [0000000000000002]: ALLOC
[ 8] .custom.b
   PROGBITS               PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000000000000006c  0
   0000000000000004 0000000000000000  0                 4
   [0000000000000202]: ALLOC, GROUP
                              ^^^^^
 ...
 ...
```

And this is the trigger of the section-type conflict error, when `custom.a` and `custom.b`
are one and the same. Gcc can't make a section that both has and does not have the `GROUP`
attribute.

Now if `get_data()` and `inline_get_data` were defined in different translation units the
compiler could not notice the conflict. So what does it matter? What would go wrong in
that case?

Nothing goes wrong in that case, because in that case there *is* no section-type conflict.
A section `custom` generated by gcc in `source.o` is a section *in* `source.o`. It must
either have or not have the `GROUP` attribute, but either way there is no conflict with
a section `custom` of the same name in `other_source.o` having the opposite status. These
are distinct input sections for the linker. It will deduplicate the input `custom` sections
that are `GROUP`ed, retaining only one of them per group-name. It will not do that
with the input `custom` sections that are not `GROUPed`, and finally it will merge
all the input `custom` sections it is left with into one output `custom` section in the binary,
with the now non-applicable `GROUP` attribute(s) ditched. That output `custom` section will 
contain `get_data()::data` as a local symbol and `inline_get_data()::inline_data` as a unique global symbol.
The conflict consists solely in the compiler encountering contradictory rules as to whether section `source.o(custom)`
shall be `GROUP`ed or not.

Why then doesn't clang fall foul of the same contradiction? It's because clang takes
a simpler but somewhat less robust approach to the problem of an *inline function with external linkage
containing static data*.

Sticking with the differentiation of sections `custom.a` and `custom.b`, let's now compile `source.cpp` with clang and inspect the relevant symbol and section characteristics:

```
$ objdump -C -t source.o | grep get_data
0000000000000000 l     O .custom.a  0000000000000004 get_data()::data
0000000000000000 l    d  .text._Z15inline_get_datav 0000000000000000 .text._Z15inline_get_datav
0000000000000010 g     F .text  000000000000000b other_get_data()
0000000000000000  w    F .text._Z15inline_get_datav 0000000000000010 inline_get_data()
0000000000000000 g     F .text  0000000000000010 get_data()
0000000000000000  w    O .custom.b  0000000000000004 inline_get_data()::inline_data
```

There's one difference there from the output of gcc. As we might expect, clang does not avail
of the GNU-specific symbol binding *unique global symbol* (`u`) for `inline_get_data()::inline_data`.
It makes that a weak symbol, like `inline_get_data()` itself.

And for the section traits we have:

```
$ readelf -t source.o
...
...
[ 8] .custom.a
   PROGBITS               PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0000000000000080  0
   0000000000000004 0000000000000000  0                 4
   [0000000000000002]: ALLOC
[ 9] .custom.b
   PROGBITS               PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0000000000000084  0
   0000000000000004 0000000000000000  0                 4
   [0000000000000002]: ALLOC
...
...
```

No difference, so no conflict. That's why we can replace the section names `custom.a`
and `custom.b` with `custom`, per original, and successfully compile.

Clang relies on its weak binding of `inline_get_data()::inline_data` to
answer the requirement that just one such symbol is addressed by every implementation
of `inline_get_data()` that gets into the linkage. This saves it from a section-type
conflict but forgoes the linkage armour-plating of gcc's more complicated approach.

Can you *tell* gcc to forgo that robustness and take a clang-like way with compiling
`inline_get_data()`? You can *a bit*, but not enough. You can give gcc the option
`-fno-gnu-unique` to instruct the compiler to forget the GNU-specfic *unique global*
symbol binding. If you do that, then it will make `inline_get_data()::inline_data`
a weak symbol, like clang; but that won't nudge it - maybe it should - to drop the section-grouping
linkage for the attributed section of the symbol, and you'll still get the section-type
conflict. I can find no option to inhibit this rather nitty-gritty code-generation
behaviour for your admittedly smelly problem code.

**Fixes**

We've seen how and why the gcc section-type conflict is provoked specifically by the
presence in the same translation unit of definitions of two functions, one *inline with external
linkage*, the other not inline, each of which attributes the same linkage section
to its static data.

I can suggest two remedies, one of them simple and safe but applicable only to one variation
of the problem, the other applicable always, but drastic and desperate.

**The Simple Safe One**

There are two ways in which the conflicting function definitions can get into the same
translation unit:-

1. Both of them are defined in the same source (`.cpp`) file.
2. The non-inline function is defined in a source file that includes a header in
   which the inline function is defined.

If you have cases of type 1, then it is just a goof on the part of whoever codes
the source file to code an inline function in it with external linkage. In this
case the inline function is *local* to its translation unit and should be `static`. If it is
made `static` then gcc's external linkage exertions disappear and the section-type
conflict with them. You have said you have no control over the code in which your
attributed section stuff is macro-injected, but its authors should be receptive
of the fact that writing inline external functions in a source file rather than
a header is a blunder and be willing to correct it.

**The Drastic Desperate One**

Cases of type 2 are more likely. For these, as far as I can see, your one hope
is to inject an assembly hack into your gcc build so that gcc's `.section` directives
regarding the attributed section in the inline external function definitions are
programmatically edited to be clang-like before the object code is generated.

Clearly, such a solution will be viable only for some set of gcc versions that you know to
generate the "right pattern of wrong `.section` directives" on which to target
your corrective hack, and a build system that uses it should sanity-check the
operative gcc version in advance.

A necessary preliminary is to modify your macro that generates the `custom` section 
attributes so that instead of uniformly generating the section name `.custom` it instead generates the
sequence `.custom.1`, `custom.2`,...,`custom.N` at successive invocations in a
translation unit. Use the preprocessor builtin `__COUNTER__` to do this, e.g.

```
#define CAT2(x,y) x##y
#define CONCAT(x,y) CAT2(x,y)
#define QUOT(x) #x
#define QUOTE(x) QUOT(x) 
#define SET_SECT() __attribute__((section(QUOTE(CONCAT(.custom.,__COUNTER__)))))
```

The point of this is just to let gcc preprocess code like:

```
const int* get_data()
{
    SET_SECT()
    static const int data = 123;

    return & data;
}

inline const int* inline_get_data()
{
    SET_SECT()
    static const int inline_data = 123;

    return & inline_data;
}
```

into code like:

```
const int* get_data()
{

    __attribute__((section(".custom.0")))
    static const int data = 123;

    return & data;
}

inline const int* inline_get_data()
{

    __attribute__((section(".custom.1")))
    static const int inline_data = 123;

    return & inline_data;
}
```

that will not provoke section-type conflicts.

With this in place and applied to `source.cpp`, you can assemble the file with gcc:

```
g++ -S source.cpp
```

and observe in the output `source.s` that the unproblematic section `custom.0`
get the `.section` directive:

```
.section    .custom.0,"a",@progbits
```

whereas the problematic section `custom.1` gets:

```
.section    .custom.1,"aG",@progbits,_ZZ15inline_get_datavE11inline_data,comdat
```

where `_ZZ15inline_get_datavE11inline_data` is the section-group name and `comdat`
tells the linker to deduplicate this section-group.

Repeat this with clang and observe that the corresponding directives are:

```
.section    .custom.0,"a",@progbits
.section    .custom.1,"a",@progbits
```

with no difference other than the section name.

So the assembly hack you require is one that will turn the like of either:

```
.section    .custom.0,"a",@progbits
.section    .custom.1,"aG",@progbits,_ZZ15inline_get_datavE11inline_data,comdat
```

into:

```
.section    .custom,"a",@progbits
```

This can be expressed by a `sed` substitution:

```
s|^\t\.section\t\.custom\.[0-9]\{1,\},"a\(G\)*",@progbits.*$|\t\.section\t\.custom,"a",@progbits|g
```

For the demo program, assuming the necessary changes to the macro apparatus, the
Drastic solution can be formulated in a makefile like so:

```
CXX ?= g++
SRCS = main.cpp source.cpp
ASMS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.s)
OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
CPPFLAGS = -I.
CXXFLAGS = -fno-gnu-unique

%.o: %.cpp

%.s: %.cpp
%.s: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -S -o $@ $<

%.o: %.s    
%.o: %.s
    sed -i 's|^\t\.section\t\.custom\.[0-9]\{1,\},"a\(G\)*",@progbits.*$$|\t\.section\t\.custom,"a",@progbits|g' $<
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

.PHONY: all clean
.INTERMEDIATE: $(ASMS)

all: prog

prog: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^

clean:
    rm -f prog $(OBJS) $(ASMS)
```

from which a `./prog` can be built with gcc that fulfils the expectation of printing `246`
on stdout.

Notice three details of the makefile:-

- We need to write empty pattern rules like `%.o: %.cpp` to delete make's inbuilt
  recipes for those rules.
- In the `sed` command we need `*$$` as the eol-marker to escape make-expansion of
  `$`.
- `-fno-gnu-unique` is passed in the compiler flags to fill-out the clang mimicry.

This is not a solution I'd want expose to an open user-base except as stop-gap. I won't 
demur if the take-away from all of it is: Isn't there's a better way of attacking the underlying the problem?

Comment: Thanks for this detailed description. FTR, there's a working abd less drastic solution, which is hand rolling both the section directive and the variable definition in asm. It comes with its own problems.

Comment: @erenon I thought of inlining the assembly late last night but feared I woudln't beat the clock with it. Good you have a less filthy fix. Cheers.

Comment: The motivation of the question is now open source, along with the asm solution to this problem: https://github.com/morganstanley/binlog/blob/hiperf/include/binlog/create_source.hpp  (better late than never?)

Answer (score 4):

Messing with custom sections is a bit of a dirty topic because gcc decides on data or bss depending on init value and does not expect you to mess with it at that level.

What I'd suggest for **user data** is to use it as you normally use data - put it in a data file. If you insist on using library, you can at least let it use its own library and then the data can be in the normal places.

A tiny user lib, can be built with `-fno-zero-initialized-in-bss` to have all the user data in the data section for easy parsing. But don't do that on your binaries.

Comment: I don't get this. The init values are the same. By your reasoning, they should go to the same section.

Comment: gcc might have decided to make the inline one `immediate`

Comment: make a static variable immediate? It produces the same result even if I pass &inline_data to a declared dummy function, without definition. It would be really surprising.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a satisfactory solution. It is really just the combination of already known techniques. The runtime uses a normal static variable, whose address is put into the custom section by inline assembly. On different platforms (clang, MSVC),`__attribute__` or `#pragma` can be used with the same results, without ASM. This solution can be easily wrapped into a generic, platform agnostic macro.

```
const int* get_data()
{
  static const int data = 123;
  __asm__(
    ".pushsection .custom, \"?\", @progbits" "\n"
    ".quad %c0" "\n"
    ".popsection" "\n"
    : : "i"(&data)
  );

  return & data;
}

inline const int* inline_get_data()
{
  static const int inline_data = 123;
  __asm__(
    ".pushsection .custom, \"?\", @progbits" "\n"
    ".quad %c0" "\n"
    ".popsection" "\n"
    : : "i"(&inline_data)
  );

  return & inline_data;
}

int main()
{
  (void) get_data();
  (void) inline_get_data();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The gcc documentation (e.g. for [5.3](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html#Variable-Attributes)) says:

> Use the section attribute with global variables and not local variables [...]

Thus, you need to extract those variables from the functions:

```
__attribute__((section(".custom"))) static const int data = 123;
__attribute__((section(".custom"))) static const int inline_data = 123;

const int* get_data()
{
  return &data;
}

inline const int* inline_get_data()
{
  return &inline_data;
}

int main()
{
  (void)get_data();
  (void)inline_get_data();
}
```

This compiles just fine with gcc-5.2 and clang-3.5.1

Comment: Please read the question: "I have no control over the function signature,the *data variables are produced by a macro provided by me, and they can appear anywhere." I read the docs, I know it's a thin ice. Still, I'm using static local variables, and this works on clang and MSVC: no good reason was provided so far why GCC fails.

Comment: Maybe you can clarify the question a bit then. I read those parts: The signature of the functions stayed the same. The data variables now appear somewhere else. It is unclear to me which part of your question I violated?

Comment: Sorry, I see now the source of confusion. I need to produce a macro, e.g: STORE(x), which can appear in any function body, stores the given `x`, and returns a handle.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. As I understand the documentation, it is unspecified behavior if you somehow make that compile and link with gcc.