# How to get more information on "X causes a section type conflict with Y"

Tags: c++, linker, aix, powerpc

I am working on a Power 8 machine running AIX (oslevel 7200-00-01-1543) and GCC 6.1 (6.1.0). We are catching the compile error shown below. I'm trying to gather more information about what is causing the conflict.

I read [Inline static data causes a section type conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35091862/608639), but its not exactly clear to me how inlining relates to a conflict caused by a (1) a destructor in one class and (2) a method in a different class (neither of which are marked for inlining).

Another good question is [GCC error “ causes a section type conflict”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30076949/608639), but we are not using linker scripts and `-fno-zero-initialized-in-bss` did not help.

I'm having trouble reducing it to a minimal test case for the same reasons, so I don't have a minimal test case at the moment.

How do we gather more information about the conflict that's causing the error? Is there a way to instruct GCC to tell us more about the sections or maybe tell us the attributes that are causing the conflict?

---

When I add the `-save-temps` flag and then inspect the artifacts I don't see anything unusual.

The person who asked the question [Section type conflict for identically defined variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30005764/608639) had the same problem. He tried to troubleshoot it but could not find additional information.

Now open in the GCC Issue Tracker: [Compile error "X causes a section type conflict with Y" should provide more information](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82209).

---

We test on a number of systems, and the AIX machine is the only one with the problem. On another Power 8 machine running openSUSE with GCC we don't experience the problem.

```
-bash-4.3$ gmake
g++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 -fPIC -pthread -pipe -c bench2.cpp
In file included from bench2.cpp:9:0:
gfpcrypt.h: In function 'CryptoPP::DL_PrivateKey_GFP<GP>::~DL_PrivateKey_GFP() [with GP = CryptoPP::DL_GroupParameters_DSA]':
gfpcrypt.h:519:13: error: CryptoPP::DL_PrivateKey_GFP<GP>::~DL_PrivateKey_GFP() [with GP = CryptoPP::DL_GroupParameters_DSA] causes a section type conflict with void CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<T, T_Align16>::deallocate(void*, CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<T, T_Align16>::size_type) [with T = unsigned char; bool T_Align16 = true]
     virtual ~DL_PrivateKey_GFP() {}
             ^
In file included from integer.h:20:0,
                 from validate.h:8,
                 from bench2.cpp:6:
secblock.h:217:7: note: 'void CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<T, T_Align16>::deallocate(void*, CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<T, T_Align16>::size_type) [with T = unsigned char; bool T_Align16 = true]' was declared here
  void deallocate(void *ptr, size_type size)
       ^~~~~~~~~~
GNUmakefile:1026: recipe for target 'bench2.o' failed
```

---

The fix for us was to move the destructor out-of-line as shown below. We have no idea what caused the problem or why it was fixed. The original question remains: how can we troubleshoot the issue in the future?

```
@@ -516,7 +516,7 @@ template <class GP>
 class DL_PrivateKey_GFP : public DL_PrivateKeyImpl<GP>
 {
 public:
-    virtual ~DL_PrivateKey_GFP() {}
+    virtual ~DL_PrivateKey_GFP();

     //! \brief Create a private key
     //! \param rng a RandomNumberGenerator derived class
@@ -570,6 +570,10 @@ class DL_PrivateKey_GFP : public DL_PrivateKeyImpl<GP>
         {this->AccessGroupParameters().Initialize(p, q, g); this->SetPrivateExponent(x);}
 };

+// Out-of-line dtor due to AIX and GCC
+template <class GP>
+DL_PrivateKey_GFP<GP>::~DL_PrivateKey_GFP() {}
+
 //! \class DL_SignatureKeys_GFP
 //! \brief Discrete Log (DL) signing/verification keys in GF(p) groups
 struct DL_SignatureKeys_GFP
```

Comment: is there a pkg.config file for CrytopPP on that machine that can give you the compiler flags that were used to compile it?

Comment: @RichardHodges - No, I'm working from Master. The compile flags used to compile the library and the test program are `-DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 -fPIC -pthread`. The same `CXXFLAGS` are used for both, and the compiler drives link to ensure the same `CXXFLAGS` are applied.

Comment: A quick scan of the source code is pointing a finger at the macro CRYPTOPP_SECTION_ALIGN16. There are a few other macros that force data into different sections for different reasons. 
I've always hated this library, I think it's broken. I use openssl.

Comment: Thanks @RichardHodges. Yeah, I tried commenting `CRYPTOPP_SECTION_ALIGN16` out already. There were a few other suspects that were commented out, too. Do you know how to instruct GCC to give us more information about the conflict?

Comment: @RichardHodges - By the way, you might like Jack Lloyd's [Botan](https://github.com/randombit/botan/issues) if you are  interested in C++ security libraries. Botan also has a different charter than OpenSSL, so it does more than just TLS. Botan offers algorithms that OpenSSL does not provide, like PQC algorithms.

Comment: i will point my security guy at it. thank you.

Comment: Maybe add "gcc" as a tag to get some gcc folks to comment?